# Heroku Bundler specific_platform true

Tags: heroku, environment-variables, bundle

I'm developing on windows and use image_optim and the image_optim_pack gems. Previously, pushing these to Heroku was not a problem, everything resolved normally. Now I get a new warning and production fails:

```
Unable to use the platform-specific (x86_64-linux) version of image_optim_pack (0.5.0.20170609) because it has different dependencies from the ruby version. 
To use the platform-specific version of the gem, run `bundle config specific_platform true` and install again.
remote: Could not find image_optim_pack-0.5.0.20170609 in any of the sources
```

I've tried to set a env var on heroku to allow this, but it seems like Heroku only allows to set vars for bundle install (e.g. --without), their article here doesn't help me:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-configuration

**Question**: How can I set platform_specific to true on Heroku?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. The correct way to add the variable is to write it like this:

```
In the KEY field:
BUNDLE_SPECIFIC_PLATFORM
In the VALUE field:
true
```

I noticed this after setting the local config for bundler and checking the text file on my machine.